# Applications moved to SD card cannot be loaded

Tags: 2.2-froyo, app2sd

I have an Android phone running Android 2.2.1 with very limited phone memory. So I have to move the applications to SD card all the time.

BUT:

If I move applications to the SD card, then after I reboot the phone, some of the (most likely the bigger in size ones) will disappear on the application panel. And the icons in the *settings → application management* will turn into a gray icon with a SD mark on it. Also the name becomes the package name like 'com.foo.bar'. If I tap the icon, only the remove button is available. This is different from the issue of icons on application panel loads slow after reboot. This issue is about the application just won't load.

Another thing on I noticed is that, on reboot, loading SD card seems done in a very short time. Maybe the system is not loading the SD card with enough time.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Can you access the SD card afterwards? Are any other files disappearing? Additionally, if (after those apps "disappeared") you take out the sd card and mount it to your computer using a card reader, can you check the `.android_secure` directory on it whether the `.apk` files are still there?

Comment: thanks for reply @Izzy photos and files on sd card are accessable as usual. I did as you told, there was a .android_secure folder, but i only saw .ases files, no any .apk files there.

Comment: I forgot to mention that they have a different extension there (should be `.asec`), as they are encrypted. Are all the "missing apps" still there? If so, you've got some problem with the App2SD service. Are you using the native method (as provided by Android itself), or any 3rd-party helper apps?

Comment: What model phone? Are you rooted? Are you using the built-in "move to SD card"? I assume that these applications work fine if they're _not_ on the SD card, yes?

Comment: Yes @Izzy , they are .asec, but seems the historical files were there too. like com.foo.bar-1.asec and com.foo.bar.asec . Yes, i moved them to sdcard with native android application management. If i leave them on the phone memory they work fine.

Comment: There are many apps that wont run from an SD Card, read some of this article http://hobbyistsoftware.com/InsideYourTreo/run-app-from-sd-card.php

Comment: Very funny, Simon: 1st, your article is on *PalmOS* (and we're talking *Android* here), and 2nd Still's apps completely disappear after a reboot (and before that were running fine from sd card). So your comment does not apply here at all, sorry.

Comment: Any one have any idea what's happening here?

Comment: I have the same problem on my Galaxy S2 (ICS 4.0.4). It's random which apps though could be the larger ones. I've seen reports of this elsewhere. It seems to be the general loading time of the card. All the apps are supposedly fine running on an sd card. Frustrating as the s2 has a poor partition size for the phone memory so can't get all my apps on it.

Answer (score -1):

Use a different Launcher like Apex and you'll be fine

Comment: Please elaborate on this. Why do you think this will solve the problem?

Comment: This is an answer.  As surmised by the OP, `the system is not loading the SD card with enough time` and the default launcher removes the icons for apps on the SD card.  Some other launchers do not do this.